# How to open different files in the active window giving the extensions with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm a newbie with AppleScript and I'm trying to open two files (.txt & .jpg) in the same folder, in the active window, so every time i double click the .jpg file, it opens those two files, i'm not sure how to do it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult. Double-clicking the jpeg file will simply open the file in whatever preferred app is specified for that file type (or that specific file). If the app is scriptable (not many are), you might be able to do something there.

You might be able to make an AppleScript application which handles .jpg files by hacking the info.plist of the application, then use a folder action which assigns your AppleScript application as the default app for any jpg files added to the folder. Quite complicated, and probably quite fragile, especially if you are a newbie.

An easier approach might be to make an AppleScript droplet, which finds the 'partner' file for any file dropped onto it (either .jpg or .txt) - based on the heuristic that the names / paths (without the extensions) are the same for each of the pair, so instead of double-clicking the jpg, you drag it on to the droplet (which could live in your dock, or in the same folder with the jpgs, or wherever you prefer).

Here's a very quick and dirty implementation.

```
on open (filez)
    repeat with fa in filez
    set ff to fa as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set folderPath to (text items 1 thru -2 of ff) as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

    set n to (name of (info for fa))
    if (n contains ".") then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set textItems to (text items of n)
        set basename to (items 1 thru -2 of textItems) as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set ext to (item -1 of textItems) as string

        if ext is in {"jpeg", "JPEG", "jpg", "JPG"} then
            set textPartner to basename & ".txt"
            if textPartner is in (list folder folderPath) then
                set textPartnerPath to folderPath & ":" & textPartner
                tell application "TextEdit" to open file textPartnerPath
            end if
            tell application "Preview" to open fa
        end if

    end if
    end repeat
end open
```